# Can the address of variable change during execution?

Tags: java, c++, c, variables, clr

I was reading address binding of variables and wondering whether the address of a variable change during the execution under any circumstances? Can it happen due to garbage collection in JVM or CLR? And what about C and C++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends greatly on the language and what you mean by *change the address*. In C++ the address of an object is what uniquely identifies it and they cannot be moved. Some managed languages (including Java and C#) use generational garbage collectors that actually move the objects around in memory (in a generational GC, object will move from one generation to another with time), but the fact is that you should not care: In those languages that you can obtain the address of the object, the address is fixed, in those where the address is fixed, it is not part of the *perceivable* state of the object...

Also note that I am using *object*, rather than variable here, as I believe this is what you are interested on. There is a fine line that separates objects and variables, for example, in Java, a reference is a variable that can be used to access an object. But I won't even try to go into the precise definitions of either...

Comment: Indeed, in C and C++ the term _object_ refers to any data type, not just class types.

Answer (score 3):

If your code has Undefined Behaviors then all bets are off and yes it might happen.
But in a valid C/C++ program the address of an variable will not change.

Comment: The address of a object **cannot** be changed in a C/C++ program. The contents can be copied or moved, but the address is what uniquely identifies the object and cannot be changed. Not in a correct program, not in a program that exhibits Undefined Behavior (unless you are one of those that believe Undefined Behavior may serve you dinner when you get home or cause demons to spawn in your neighborhood...)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Technically, *Undefined Behavior may serve you dinner when you get home or cause demons to spawn in your neighborhood...* Yes, It can.Practically, it never will. Yes I choose to adhere to the former school of thought & hasn't & it doesn't hurt to stick to that,infact it helps most of the times.

Answer (score 1):

In a valid C/C++ program unless your code changes the address of the variable deliberately or otherwise, the address will not be changed by the execution environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely to change but don't base your code around the assumption that it won't.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the address of some kinds of variables can change (e.g. static or instance fields), and others typically can't (e.g. local variables).  For current generation JVMs, thread stacks live in memory segments outside of the heap, and the GC does not move them.

However, this is moot with respect to "taking the address of a variable", because you can't do that in Java.  (If you could, then it would be the responsibility of GC to deal with relocation.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, variable continues to refer to the same value or memory location in program's execution time. But this can be changed, making it `uninitialized` (having an undefined value), so it has yet to be explicitly given a particular value. This may give unpredictable results. To handle such an issue, space needed for a variable in memory may be allocated only when the variable is first used and freed when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ the address won't change.

Be aware that in c++ you can override the & operator though for variables of class tyoe, so even though the address won't change, the value you might get from &variable might change (which isn't the address changing but might be confusing)

Comment: John could you please explain your point with a small example code. It will be very helpful. Thanks